# AOE spells vs high ground in4E

Tags: dnd-4e

In my next campain my group will face a chokepoint with archers on top of the mountain and melee down where they need to pass exept if they want to climb to get up on the high ground.
My question is can our wizard hit both the people on the ground and the ones on the top (50 feet high cliff) at the same time (with the same attack)

Comment: What spells does the wizard have access to?

Answer (score 8):

In canonical two-dimension combat, blasts and bursts have a square shape (approximating a round one). If the third dimension is relevant, remember that blasts and bursts are cubical (approximating a sphere).

So, an area burst 3 is a 7x7x7 cube. You have to aim the center of your spell (the **origin square**) 4 squares above ground in order to fill the entire volume of the cube.

50 feet equal 10 squares, so you need a really huge burst (at least an area burst 5 that produces a 11x11x11 cube). If you could accomplish this, and there are no obstructions from the center of the burst to your targets, you can hit both the ground-based melee and the archers on the cliff.

Comment: thank you for this nice explanation! Is there by anny chance also a ruling what this will do for archers on the clif and archers down? Will i have to ad these 10 squares up to the reach of the archer down and on the clif?

Comment: If I correctly interpreted your comment, yes. Vertical distance **is** a factor. When determining the distance between 2 places (for example, when determining if a target is in range) imagine a cuboid where the 2 places are at opposite vertexes. The distance, in squares, is equal to the longest edge of the cuboid.

Comment: So, if an archer is 2 squares away from you (on the map) but 10 squares over your head, the distance between you and the archer is 10 squares. If the archer is 15 squares away (on the map) and 10 squares over your head, the distance between you and the archer is 15 squares.

Comment: In published encounters, I've typically seen heights that are only about 10 or 20ft up. I think it gets too confusing if you make them 50ft up (because of the typical range being only 10 for ranged attacks) And definitely don't be mean and make it 55ft up.